# Rspberry pi python programming for GPIO with if/else contition

Tags: python, if-statement, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am trying to generate a pulse train (using raspberry pi zero w) and read that pulse train (using an analog to digital converter AD1015 module). Below shows my code.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

import time

import Adafruit_ADS1x15

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

import time

import Adafruit_ADS1x15

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

ADC = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1015()

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(4,GPIO.OUT)

GAIN = 1

print('Reading ADS1x15values, press Ctrl+C to quite')

print('|{0:>6}|'.format(*range(1)))

print('-'*37)

while(1):
      
     GPIO.output(4,GPIO.HIGH)
     time.sleep(5)
     GPIO.output(4,GPIO.LOW)
     time.sleep(5)

A = GPIO.output(4)

 if (A == True):
      
     for i in range(1):
        values = [0]*1 
        values[i] = ADC.read_adc(i,gain=GAIN)
        print('|{0:>6}|'.format(*values))|
        time.sleep(0.5)
        
 else:
     
    for i in range(1):
        values[i] = ADC.read_adc(i,gain=GAIN)
        print('|{0:>6}|'.format(*values))
        time.sleep(0.5)

        time.sleep(0.1)
```

My problem is after compiling this code it gives no analog to digital converted reading as result. Below show my result after compilation.

After compilation given result
[image: After compilation given result]

Can anyone help me work on this?

Comment: as for me you have wrong indentations and you try to print it after loop `while(1)` but this loop will never end. You have to run it inside loop `while(1)` or you would have to run loop `while(1)` in separated thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a pulse train why don't you check out this:
https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating_from_rpigpio.html?highlight=pwm#pwm-pulse-width-modulation

Then verify if you can read the I2C address of your sensor with this: https://linux.die.net/man/8/i2cdetect

Then you have to read the datasheet of the ADC to know what register you can read.
Install the SMBU2 library and the use these functions:
https://smbus2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/